# tinymce toolbar is missing in Chrome

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tinymce

I'm using tinymce for a text editor on my web project handled by Jquery-1.7.1. FYI, It's SPA, Single Page Application, so there's no refresh on every page move.

Here's the thing. for the very first try to open a page which has the editor, its toolbar doesn't appear. And for my second try, it does appear. interesting huh?

I'm going to give you more details on this. it seems that the toolbar appears for less than a sec, and then it's gone immedieately. But I can sense that there's a moment it appears for very short time.

So I pressed F12, took out the dev tool, and checked if the required HTML elements exist or not. Unfortunately they do, which drives me crazy.

Using secondary monitor, I put two browser screens on each, and inspected it throughoutly, hoping that there would be a CSS discrepancy between the two !! But, all to no avail.

I found nothing. what they have is identical. But one shows the toolbar, another doesn't. I can't get it. I think I'm not able to. There's no error or alert notification on the browser console window, not a single one.

If there were a script error or something like that, I would be able to deal with this problem easily. But there's no clue what causes this stupid ui malfunction. Please help me out, or give me some clue.

Answer (score 0):

Does the whole toolbar disappear? Or only some buttons disappear?
Please tell us your **browser version**.

Depending on your browser's window width, some buttons may be hidden behind the right column.

Thank you.

Comment: It's chrome latest. and the whole toolbar disappear, more acurately, it doesn't show up on a web page.

Comment: Alright, if that's the case, you should use the Ckeditor. It works and does a better job and the tiny editor is not completed and might present some bugs.

Comment: no joke. I didn't put this question up on this web at the first place, if I knew that I would get a question like you gave me. no recommendation for other plugin is needed. what a..